# How to sort GRIDVIEW table (no datasource) with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, gridview

I create gridview myself and no connected to database.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AllowSorting="True">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Dene1" SortExpression="Dene1" > </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Dene2" SortExpression="Dene2" > </asp:BoundField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim number As New System.Random()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing

    For i = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text)
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    GridView3.DataSource = dt
    GridView3.DataBind()

    For i = 0 To Val(TextBox1.Text)
        GridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text = number.Next(0, 10)
        GridView3.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text = number.Next(10, 20)
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to sort any column.

```
Private Sub GridView3_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView3.Sorting
    Dim dt As New DataTable("GridView3")
    Dim view As New DataView(dt)

    view.Sort = String.Format(“{0} {1}”, "Dene1", "ASC") 'alternative-1
    view.Sort = "Dene1 ASC"                              'alternative-2
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Dene1 ASC"                    'alternative-3

    GridView3.DataBind()
End Sub
```

All alternatives do not work. The error message is "can not find column "Dene1".
How can I solve this or How can I sorting gridview table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give you data table column a name:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
....
....
dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Dene1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But the error is "0 number column not found".

Answer (score 0):

As per JustinHui answer the datatable will need columns with a name however I have also noted something else.

```
Private Sub GridView3_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView3.Sorting
    Dim dt As New DataTable("GridView3")
    Dim view As New DataView(dt)

    view.Sort = String.Format(“{0} {1}”, "Dene1", "ASC") 'alternative-1
    view.Sort = "Dene1 ASC"                              'alternative-2
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Dene1 ASC"                    'alternative-3
    Gridview3.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    GridView3.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Surely you need to add the datasource of data grid otherwise what are you binding? You seem to be missing it.

```
Gridview3.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `DataField` attribute.  Here is my designer code from a similar implementation.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" > 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"  ItemStyle-Width="150"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width ="150"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in the code behind.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But if I descripe "DataField", the error is "data source connection".